# Django app not found despite adding to INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: python, django, makemigrations

its just a sample app,

app name:wiki

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

class Page(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
content = models.TextField(blank=True)

#settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'wiki.apps.WikiConfig',
'wikicamp.wiki',
'wiki',
]
```

(i tried all the possible links/address of the app i.e wiki, and even individually too)

and it still show the following error on running:
**python3 manage.py makemigrations wiki**

Error: **App 'wiki' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?**

Comment: can you show the directory structure of `wiki` (including file names)?

Comment: Adding it to installed_apps doesn't do anything at all to actually make it available to be imported by the rest of your code

Comment: i thought about that whole looking at the  Polls app, but still, how to solve this ?

Comment: @pbhowmick /wikicamp/(wiki/ -"(migration)(_pycache)(admin.py)(apps.py)(init.py)(models.py)(tests.py)(views.py)(urls.py) )"
(wikicamp - )(db.sqlite3)(manage.py)

Comment: You have a init.py file but it should be __init__.py to set wiki as a python module

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `__init__.py` right under `wiki`

Comment: no it's just there, the __init__.py file. i haven't tweaked any of the file structure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that was a virtual env issue. I restart my virtual environment and run python migrate. I had several packages that were missing in the virtualenv, some not related to the initial message.