# TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/create/

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

When I click on create post it takes me to `.../blog/create/` and I get this error: `TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/create/`

[image]

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang*en>
<head>
    <title>This is the Title</title>
    {% include 'snippets/header.html' %}
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Body -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .main{
            min-height: 100vh;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="main">
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock content %}
    </div>

    {% include 'snippets/footer.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

**blog/Template/blog/create.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <p>Create a new blog...</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from blog.views import(
    create_blog_view,
)

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', create_blog_view, name="create"),
]
```

**main urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from personal.views import (
    home_screen_view,
)

from account.views import (
    registration_view,
    logout_view,
    login_view,
    account_view,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_screen_view, name="home"),
    path('register/', registration_view, name="register"),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', 'blog')),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name="logout"),
    path('login/', login_view, name="login"),
    path('account/', account_view, name="account"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**blog/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import BlogPost

def create_blog_view(request):
    return render(request, "blog/create.html", {})
```

**personal/Template/snippets/home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<style type="text/css">
    @media (max-width: 768px) { 
        .right-column{
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) { 
        .right-column{
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    }

    .blog-post-container{
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .create-post-bar{
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    .left-column{
        padding:0px;
    }

    .right-column{
        padding:0px;
    }

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="create-post-bar d-lg-none col-lg-7 offset-lg-1">
            <a href="{% url 'blog:create' %}">Create post</a>
        </div>

        <div class="left-column col-lg-7 offset-lg-1">
            <div class="blog-post-container">
                <p>Thingy</p>
            </div>

            <div class="blog-post-container">
                <p>Thingy</p>
            </div>

            <div class="blog-post-container">
                <p>Thingy</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-column col-lg-3 d-lg-flex d-none flex-column">
            <div class="create-post-bar">
                <p>Stuff</p>
                <p>Stuff</p>
                <p>Stuff</p>
                <a class="p-2 btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'blog:create' %}">Create post</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path

import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'personal',
    'account',
    'blog',

    #Djangos apps

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Account'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
...
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn')
```

I was expecting it to redirect me to the new page but it shows an error.

Comment: last code is settings.py

Answer (score 1):

With [APP_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) enabled Django searches for templates inside each app `/templates/` subfolder. Lowercase, plural.

You have `Template` - wrong case, missing `s` in the end. So yes, the template does not exist for Django because it cannot be found at any expected location.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your app doesn't look into `blog`'s template folder. It only looks into `personal`
and `account`'s template folders. You can check that in the attached picture under `template-loader postmortem`. It usually means that the app is not installed properly.

There are lots of reasons for such a thing, among them:

- You might have located it in a wrong directory. The app must be at `./src/`. It seems that it's not the case as the `url.py` is working properly.
- It might be the case that you forgot to save `settings.py` after you added the `blog` app.
- It might be your virtual environment. [A restart and a migrate command might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952966/django-app-not-found-despite-adding-to-installed-apps#34955252).

Otherwise you might have changed the app's template directory somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have, in your settings.py, the configuration

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates')],
```

so you need to have the Templates directory in your base directory, not inside each app, it should be

```
Template/blog/create.html
```

and not

```
blog/Template/blog/create.html
```